# Help translate from class to function React Component

Tags: reactjs

Help translate from class to function React Component

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это сообщество на русском, поэтому пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос. И если вы хотите функциональный компонент без `state` - не получится.

Comment: И вместо картинки кода - прикрепите сам код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант - это вынести логику получения данных (ваш `fetch`) в другое место, а далее спускать эти данные в виде `props`, или даже контекстом (если очень высоко по дереву).

Еще как вариант - вынести это в `redux`. Это несколько неоднозначно выносить получение данных для одного компонента в глобальное хранилище, но в крупных проектах - самый комфортный подход.

Для первого варианта должно получится что-то вроде

```
const Background = props => {
  const { pictures } = this.props;
  const renderPictures = () => {
    return pictures.map(picture => (
      <div key={picture.results}>....</div>
    ))
  }
   return (
 <div>{renderPictures()}</div>
)
}
```

И где-то в родительском компоненте:

```
<Background pictures={this.state.pictures} />
```

Предполагается, что вы вынесли логику занесения картинок в `state` родительского компонента.

В случае, если вы пользуетесь `redux` - создавайте контейнер с помощью `connect` функции в библиотеке `react-redux`, делайте запрос в каком-нибудь `middleware`(`redux-saga` или `redux-thunk` - самые популярные), доставайте так-же из `props`